# The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character

Tags: xml

I've an XML schema that references the a well-known schema hosted on the web.

http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.xsd

Via:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.xsd"/>
```

Via dependencies I haven't chased down, it references this:

http://www.w3.org/XML/2000/xmlschema/versionInfo.ent

Which has a validation error according to Xerces, saying:

> The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character.

This was causing my entire schema chain to fail validation. I've removed the `xs:import` from any my schemas and now its fine, but is there a problem with this `.ent` file?

It seems a common error in Google and I wonder if other systems are hitting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you display that document in your browser it includes the following near the start:

```
<documentation>
!!!THIS SCHEMA DOCUMENT IS OUT OF DATE!!! It uses a preliminary W3C XML Schema
syntax which has been superseded. The up-to-date version is at
http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd
</documentation>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael (and derp). I'll reintroduce the import and have a look when I'm next in the office. I didn't consider it was out-of-date, the import was auto-added by Oxygen's schema gen (Tring??).